# React output component from props in Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to pass a component from a parent to a modal children. This is the "path" of the component that is passing:

first step:

```
<DataGrid 
    rows = {rows} 
    columns = {columns} 
    addEditForm={<LabourDescAddEditForm row={row} />}
    setRow = {setRow} />
```

second step (modalform inside datagrid)

```
<ModalForm 
      show={show} 
      title={title}
      addEditForm={props.addEditForm} 
      submitFormEdit={props.submitFormEdit}
      submitFormAdd={props.submitFormAdd}/>
```

final step

```
function ModalForm(props) {
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
setModal(props.show)
console.log(props) 
},[props])

return (
<div>
  <Modal show={modal} onHide={props.handleClose} >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>{props.title}</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      {props.AddEditForm}
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button onClick={props.handleClose}>
        Close
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={props.item ? props.submitFormEdit : props.submitFormAdd}>
        {props.buttonLabel}
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
  </div>
 )
}
```

On console.log(props) i can see the component:

```
{show: false, title: "", addEditForm: {…}, buttonLabel: "", handleClose: ƒ, …} 
(if i click on extend row)
addEditForm: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
buttonLabel: ""
handleClose: () => setShow(false)
show: false
submitFormAdd: e => {…}
submitFormEdit: e => {…}
title: ""
__proto__: Object
}
```

But i don't understand why the modal body is empty. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say

> i can see the component: **addEditForm**

You write in code

```
 {props.AddEditForm}
```

You have some typo

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing in `AddEditForm` wherever you use your Modal, you need to ensure that it is passed like `AddEditForm={<EditForm/>}`

Comment: please see the question updated, sorry! thank you for helping me

Comment: ah, in this case check your capitalization like Alex suggested :)